# SSIS Package to pull data from multiple excel files - getting on error on 'Expression Properties'

Tags: sql-server, excel, visual-studio-2012, ssis, etl

Need some help please. I am getting Source Connection error when I try to make it dynamic.

I am using Visual Studio 2010, Excel 2010, SQL 2012 running on WIN 2008.

I am trying to do this in VS: Connection Manager (Source) – I have SQL 2012 and Excel 2010 / 2016

Steps:

1. Rt Click on 'SOURCE Connection under Data Flow tab and Click Properties
2. Under Expression Properties, Select String Property and click on expression icon and Create String statement for EXPRESSIONS (for dynamic folder) – I am using this expression

`"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
+@[User::FileName]+";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0:HDR=Yes\";"`

The above breaks Source Connection.. I am attaching screen shots

Please help. Thank you

[image: Connection Error]

[image: Connection Error]

[image: Connection Error]

Comment: Does this work when you hard-code a reference to an Excel file?

Comment: I was following an example from internet and before adding this string, it worked for one file

Comment: Can you share the value held in *User::FileName* when it fails?

Comment: Sorry I am a newbi :-) .. don't know how to find that. Please guide..

Comment: No need to apologise. We've all been there. You can use the immediate window to inspect variable values while your package is running. This [blog post](http://datachix.com/2010/12/28/debugging-ssis-variables-part-two/) includes a nice guide. This is a handy technique to learn.

Comment: In extended properties why using `:` Replace it with `;`

Answer (score 1):

**First**

In extended properties why using `:` Replace it with
`;`

**Second**

For excel 2007 files and newer `.xlsx` you have to use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB` Provider instead of `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB`

your connection string must be like the following :

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES";`

you expression might look like:

`"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
+@[User::FileName]+";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes\";"`